# Is there any way Chromebook child security can be loosened to allow my child to install apps but allow me to monitor activity?

Tags: monitoring, chromebook

I recently bought a Chromebook for my daughter. I made her a child Google account, under my account. I signed into the Chromebook with her account, and I find her account isn't allowed to install any apps, or really do anything on the Chromebook.

From some of what I've read (I can find and link the articles later), this is a Google thing, and they aren't going to fix it anytime soon. Is this correct?

Is there a way to allow her to use the Chromebook, under her account or mine, while I can still monitor her activity and control what apps she installs?

Comment: You should do more research on the child controls on Chromebook. I'm not personally familiar with this, but most parental control systems allow you to specify the apps that are allowed, and give you a way to install these.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has not done any research. Google has an easily found official document explaining this exact process.

Comment: https://support.google.com/families/answer/7680868?hl=en

Comment: @music2myear from the link posted "Children can't use apps and extensions in Chrome" and my question (exactly asking about this) is there a way to let kids use apps, while still being able to monitor them

Comment: I might have found an answer on another question. I'll do some more research and push the duplicate through if warranted